# Most optimal way of running intensive math calculations on a GPU

Tags: algorithm, gpu, opencl, boolean-logic

I am doing some academic/educational research (topic is related to boolean logic and it's extensions), and there is a mathematical algorithm that I would like to verify over some large set of numbers, more specifically, every integer number from 1 to 2^63. To verify it, I must run the algorithm for each of these numbers, sum the outputs and compare them to some already known pre-defined value. The resulting sum will not be larger than the amount of numbers itself.

I have a C++ host program and an OpenCL kernel that does the actual computation, and it worked fine for values from 1 to 2^32 on an NVIDIA RTX 3060 GPU on a on-demand pod that I rented for few hours - the computation took up to 10-20 seconds with all cores of GPU being used.

However, certainly, when trying to use the same approach for 2^63 numbers, the run time increased exponentially and it would not be possible for me to get a result in my mortal lifetime.

I am now looking for a way to parallelize or optimize this task, and I am bit stuck on:

1. What application-level tools should I use to achieve parallelization with a given OpenCL kernel?
2. Are there online services that provide maybe a UI or API for running such programs on a large cluster of computational devices for a reasonable price? I know some universities have such clusters, but seems most of them are private solutions not available for public.

I am looking for a way to speed the computation of the result for 2^63 integers to a few weeks of constant computation at max.

The algorithm itself is a bruteforce one with time-complexity at worst case of O(n^2) where n is the number of bits of an individual integer number that is tested by it, and **this cannot be improved or changed, it's intentionally made for bruteforcing over a large set of numbers and for now, my task is to prove it's correctness**. The kernel itself contains as many optimizations as possible, some of them also exit-early if some of the criteria is matched, avoiding the computationally-expensive operations if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would you be happy with a statistic test? Say, select 2^32 tests among all 2^64 tests.

Comment: Maybe you could prove, e.g. using a proof assistant or maybe even something limited like SAT, that certain parts of the problem space have specific properties and then use these results to avoid doing a lot of the calculations?

Comment: @SamMason thanks for suggestion, I will try to redesign the problem and avoid calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make a rough guesstimate of the number of operations required to perform your test.

```
n = max no. of bits of argument

Assume Ops to test one integer = c*n^2 for some constant c

TotalOps = c*sum_{i=1 to 63} (2^(i-1))(i^2) approx. = c*3.5e+22
```

Estimating c from the OP's earlier test...

```
c*sum_{i=1 to 32} (2^(i-1))(i^2) approx. = c*4.1e+12
```

Suppose that was 100 trillion operations (10s @ 10 trillion ops/s), that would make c approx. = 25.

Suppose you can perform 10 trillion operations per second on a single GPU. Then it would take c*3.5e+9 GPU seconds, or about 2,800 GPU years. Unless you have a sizeable budget for this, then it's a non-starter. To perform 2800GPU years of work in 1 month means using 33,000 (RTX 3060) GPUs. That's a modern exascale supercomputer, for a month. A wealthy nation state might be able to do this, but the cost would probably be many millions, even if such machines were available to hire for general purpose work, which they might not be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already did these calculations. Any how, this "answer" fits better as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the estimate, I suspected that it's currently a no-starter for modern commerically available computational powers. Telling "computing for 2^63 numbers it's not possible for today" is also a result and a summary I can put to the task

Comment: @MrOnlineCoder I made some mistakes in the calculation which I've corrected, though the final verdict is not materially different.

Comment: Another idea might be to design your own ASIC to do it, but still, that's quite a big money project. The top bitcoin mining ASICs units can do something like 100 trillion sha256 hashes/s. Supposing a single hash is around a thousand operations, that's 10^17 ops/s which could do it in a few months. As an intermediate experiment, you could check out FPGA performance. Intel has a development kit which allegedly allows you to run OpenCL on FPGAs, but the license is a few thousand dollars.

Comment: I would mention that 2800 GPU * years is not _that_ outlandish. Big part of supercomputers is in the interconnect allowing the data exchange between nodes. From the description, OPs problem is embarrassingly parallel: one can have each GPU calculate its chunk completely independently. Getting a lot of GPUs is easier than getting a proper supercomputer. For example, see, e.g., Folding@Home statistics https://stats.foldingathome.org/os, or other grid computing projects ran on volunteer's hardware. That's still *a lot* and not trivial to get, but not "wealthy nation state" level.

Comment: @aland If you have insights into how to utilise distributed networks like the one you mentioned, it would be interesting if you could write up what you know as an answer. It isn't something I know anything about, but you're right, it sounds like it could be something worth considering for this project. The OP did say 'I am looking for a way to speed the computation of the result for 2^63 integers to a few weeks of constant computation at max.' which makes the job a particularly difficult challenge. The stats you linked to show approx 4000 * 10Tflops GPUs on the whole network.